# A simpler approach to solve "how many k-permutations of aaabbccdef are there?"

Tags: combinatorics

Given a problem as follows.

> How many 4-permutations of "aaabbccdef" are there?

## Attempt

Divide the problem into disjoint cases:

- 4-permutation of $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$
- permutation of $\{2*x, y, z\}$
- permutation of $\{2*x, 2*y\}$
- permutation of $\{3*a, x\}$

The number of permutations for

- case 1: $P^6_4=360$
- case 2: $C^3_1\times C^5_2\times\frac{4!}{2!}=360$
- case 3: $C^3_2\times \frac{4!}{2!\times 2!}=18$
- case 4: $C^5_1\times \frac{4!}{3!}=20$

Total number of permutation is $758$.

## Question

Is there any simpler approach which is very useful for longer words to be made?

Comment: I have checked with Mathematica `Permutations[StringSplit["aaabbccdef", ""], {4}] // Length` and my answer is correct but it becomes complicated for longer words.

Comment: One way is to do this is to take $4!$ times the coefficient of $x^4$ in  $(1 + x + x^2/2!+x^3/3!) (1+x + x^2/2!)^2(1+x)^3$ which [comes out to](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%281+%2B+x+%2B+x%5E2%2F2%21%2Bx%5E3%2F3%21%29+%281%2Bx+%2B+x%5E2%2F2%21%29%5E2%281%2Bx%29%5E3) $379/12 \cdot 24 = 758$.  You get a factor of $1 +x + \cdots + x^k/k!$ for each distinct letter, where $k$ is the number of times the letter is used.  See my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125834/a-general-formula-for-n-distinguishable-arrangements-of-length-ell-of-a-seq/129125) question.

Comment: Well, it's arguably a duplicate of that previous question, but I can post that as an answer and let others mark as duplicate if they wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to do this is to use exponential generating functions: take $4!$ times the coefficient of $x^4$ in  $$\left(1 + x + x^2/2!+x^3/3!\right) \left(1+x + x^2/2!\right)^2\left(1+x\right)^3$$ which [comes out to](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%281+%2B+x+%2B+x%5E2%2F2%21%2Bx%5E3%2F3%21%29+%281%2Bx+%2B+x%5E2%2F2%21%29%5E2%281%2Bx%29%5E3) $379/12 \cdot 24 = 758$.  We get this product by taking a factor of $$1 +x + \cdots + x^k/k!$$ for each distinct letter, where $k$ is the number of times the letter is used; hence $1+x + x^2/2! + x^3/3!$ for `aaa`, one $1 + x + x^2/2!$ for each of `bb` and `cc`, and a $1+x$ for each of $d,e,f$.  See my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125834/a-general-formula-for-n-distinguishable-arrangements-of-length-ell-of-a-seq/129125) question for the details, but I can explain more if it is unclear.  Essentially this is just another way of writing that we sum the multinomial formula for each choice of multiset of size $4$.

Comment: Sorry. Can we use ordinary (as opposed to exponential) generating function here?

Comment: Not that I know of. (No need for apologies...)

Comment: Thank you very much!